# How to create INNER JOIN multiple tables in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, select, inner-join

I have 3 tables: Products, Vendors and Prices. Prices has product_id and vendor_id as foreign keys. Now i want to show Prices as:

price_id:product_name:vendor_name:price

Something like:

```
SELECT p.product, v.vendor, pc.price
FROM Products AS p,
Vendors AS v
INNER JOIN Prices AS pc
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
INNER JOIN Prices AS pc
ON v.vendor = pc.vendor_id
```

but I didnt get it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT pr.price_id, p.product_name v.vendor_name, pr.price
FROM Prices AS pr
LEFT JOIN Products AS p ON p.product_id = pr.product_id
LEFT JOIN Vendors AS v ON v.vendor = pr.vendor_id
```

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER`? The question states that `product_id` and `vendor_id` are both constrained by foreign keys. So there shouldn't be the possibility of an entry in the price table that does not join to a vendor/product.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same alias twice

```
Prices as pc
```

You can only use pc once.

Answer (score 0):

or write 3 diffent select statements and join them with UNION

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have 3 different tables, and this query works well.

```
SELECT A.ID_USER,A.NAME,D.ADDRESS,B.ID_STATE,B.STATE,A.ID_COUNTRY,C.COUNTRY 
FROM market.USER A 
    INNER JOIN market.state B
ON   A.ID_STATE=B.ID_STATE 
    INNER JOIN market.country C
ON A.ID_COUNTRY=C.ID_COUNTRY
    INNER JOIN market.contact D
ON A.ID_CONTACT=D.ID_CONTACT
```

try to do that for your own requirement.